# programmatic access to PDF table of contents

Tags: pdf

Many PDF documents contain a hierarchical table of contents. I am not referring to the ToC visible on a page-- what I mean is the metadata that is used to generate the sidebar links when viewing a PDF with an app like Preview. How can I extract it? I am not looking for a GUI app, as I am going to be extracting this information from many documents with a script.

Comment: Can you ask this in a way which doesn't sound like you are asking for a software recommendation? http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @krowe Hmm well I think the best I can do is remove "with a command line tool or something similar". I will be happy with a software recommendation, but I am also open to a more general description of how to access this metadata. I feel that this is a concrete, well-scoped question that meets the posting criteria. It just happens that the answer may involve a software recommendation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431426/extract-toc-of-pdf

Answer (score 0):

The python package [pdfminer](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer) is able to extract this information. Use the dumppdf.py script that comes with the package.

```
dumppdf.py -T /path/to/my/PDF
```

Produces XML of the table of contents.

**NOTE**: Credit @krowe for linking the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431426/extract-toc-of-pdf) of this answer in the comments.